# Create a has_many :posts for categories in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to the category I create in relation with the post I want to create.  I don't want to add a gem or anything else I think we can do it with `has_many`and `belongs_to`

I create two tables Posts and Category and I want to choose a category in a collection and this is written in the post new#view I want to create and on the post show#view and post index#view.

Models for posts is :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :category

  TAGS = ["Design", "Mode", "Tendance", "Life-Style", "Tradition", "Gastronomie", "Insolite", "Technologie"]
  validates :tag, inclusion: { in: Post::TAGS, allow_nil: false }

  mount_uploader :cover, ImageUploader
end
```

and categories is foreign keys for posts here is the model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :posts

  NAMES = ["JAPON", "CHINE", "INDE"]
  validates :name, inclusion: { in: Category::NAMES, allow_nil: false }

end
```

Posts Controllers are here

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    # @alert_message = "Vous lisez #{@post.title}"
  end

  def new
    # if current_user and current_user.admin?
      @post = Post.new
    # else
    #   redirect_to posts_path
    # end
  end

  def create
    # if current_user and current_user.admin?
     @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
      #@post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
      if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
      else
        render :new
      end
    # else
    #   render 'shared/404.html.erb'
    # end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # def set_category
  #   @post_category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  # end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :subtitle, :introduction, :body, :cover, :tag, :category_id)
  end
end
```

and `categories_controller` are here

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :new, :create, :destroy]

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private


  # def set_post
  #   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  # end

  # def set_category
  #   @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  # end

    def set_category
      if params[:id].present?
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
      else
        @category = Category.new
      end
    end

  #  def find_category
  #   @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  # end

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

Please could you show the right way to add a category I choose in collection and I show in post new#view show#view index#view.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please expand on your last sentence "Please could you show the right way to add a category I choose in collection and I show in post new#view show#view index#view." Do you want to assign a post to a category as it is created, or do you want to assign a post to a category later in the process?

Comment: @JackCollins I want to assign a or many post(s) to a category Display the category I choose in post new#view like You write a new post in category Japan for example. Display Category in post show#view like a little tab at the top of the article and display in the post index#view.

Answer (score 0):

If a category can belong to more than one post, I would recommend using a has_may_through relationship for your data model.

```
class Post
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :categories, through: post_categories

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end

class Category
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :posts, through: post_categories
end

class PostCategory
  belongs_to :posts
  belongs_to :categories
end
```

You will need to create a migration to add the 'through' table, PostCategory, which will consist of a post_id and a category_id.

In the controller

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.categories.build
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :subtitle, :introduction, :body, :cover, :tag, category_ids: [])
end
```

In your form, you can use fields_for to build the form for categories.

If you set this all up, rails will handle the creation of the category when the post is created. Then you will be able to call category.posts to get all the posts with that category and you can call post.categories to get all the categories assigned to the post.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think he is setting this up so that a `Post` `belongs_to` a `Category`. However, if that is not the case and you are looking for a `Post` to `has_many` `Categories`, then this answer is correct @Baptiste

Comment: @margo In the controller Post Category you mean?

Comment: @JackCollins To be sure I want a category could have many Posts like a wordpress and a post belongs_to one Category. Like that I can choose a category first and create a Post in relation to the category theme.

Comment: @JackCollins, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a `Post` to a `Category` can be accomplished in the `create` method of your `PostsController`. You are already passing the `category_id` to the controller via the `params`.

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  if @post.save && (@category.posts << @post)
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

When you are trying to `show` a post in a view, you should be able to access that `category` directly.

```
<%= post.category.name %>
```

If you allow some posts to be created without a category, you can simply not show anything, or show a "No Category" message.

```
# Don't show anything if the post doesn't belong to a category
<%= post.category.name if post.category.present? %>

# Show a "No Categories" message (this uses the ternary operator)
<%= post.category.present? ? post.category.name : "No Category" %>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand what can I call <%= post.category.name %> because I have an error `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: You're getting that error as you probably dont have a category for that post. In the form to create a post, you can use a collection_select to choose the Category - <% collection_select :category, :id, Category.all, :id, :name %>. That should assign the category to the post when you submit the post form and then you can use post.category.name.

Comment: @BaptisteB. margo is correct about assigning the category. If you want to protect against cases where a `Post` doesn't have a `Category`, see my updated answer